# Views - using "admin/" in path gets me to the home page

Tags: views, uri

I'm having an issue with the Views module.
Let me say in advance that the site urls have been customized with the module "rename admin path" and the path to the administration section is www.site.com/gestione/ , using www.site.com/admin/ will get me a "page not found" error. I thought this was something worth telling.
I want to make a view which as an administration layout and i have been told this can be achieved but using "admin/" ("gestione/" in my case) inside the path. So i put /gestione/my-archive as URL.

Now if i try to access the page i see the administration home page instead of the view. If i don't put any prefix (so that the url is www.site.com/my-archive) it works, but it has the normal front end layout, i have tried:

- "gestione/content/my-archive" brings me to the content section of the administration menu
- Any variation like "gestione/test/my-archive" still gets me to the administration home (likewise "gestione/content/test/my-archive" brings me to the content section)
- Giving no access restriction
- Anything that doesn't start with "gestione" will get me to the view but with front end layout
- using "admin/" will give me a page not found error
- Rebuilding the menu calling menu_rebuild();
- Deleting the caches

EDIT: disabling the "rename admin path" and using /admin/my-archive did the job, but i wonder if there's any way to keep it working

Comment: Have you tried configuring the view to have `/admin/my-archive` as the URL and then accessing it via `/gestione/my-archive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the view to have `/admin/my-archive` as the URL and then access it via `/gestione/my-archive`. *Rename Admin Paths* works using `hook_url_inbound_alter()` and `hook_url_outbound_alter()` which means that internally the path is still `admin/*`.